# Import .VCF file by ADB

Tags: java, android, android-studio, adb, root

I have a .VCF file in my phone: /sdcard/contacts.vcf.
I manually tried to import this file to the Android Contacts app and It worked well.
However, when I tried with the below ADB command, I got a toast message: "Couldn't import VCard".

```
adb shell am start -t "text/x-vcard" -d "file:///sdcard/contacts.vcf" -a android.intent.action.VIEW com.android.contacts
```

Android: **One (LineageOS)**

Device: **Samsung S7(Rooted).**

Is there anyone who can please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I could import a .vcf file into the default contacts app of LineageOS I had change the following:

- replace  all instances of `VERSION:4.0` with `VERSION:2.1`
- remove all occurrences of `PREF=1`

Answer (score 1):

My thanks to [Kinifwyne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64799100/import-vcf-file-by-adb/67842417#67842417) who got me onto the right path in fixing this problem. In my case, I was trying to export contacts from Thunderbird to Lineage 18.1. My version of Thunderbird exports VCards in version 4.0 format.

To resolve, I had to take the following steps in editing the Vcard file:

- Find & Replace - all instances of `VERSION:4.0` to become
  `VERSION:2.1`
- Remove all occurrences of `PREF=1`
- Remove all occurrences of multiple semicolons side-by-side; so a find & replace for `;;`
  until there are only single `;` remaining.

I was then able to import the file into Lineage.

N.B. Amongst some other fields, Birthday data doesn't transfer over from V4.0 to V2.1 during the import into Lineage (no need to remove as part of the preparation of the VCF file though - the data is just ignored). If the data were stored in the Notes field, it should be fine.

Hope this helps someone else.